# Can we convert a matlab built in function to c/c++ code using matlab coder

Tags: c++, matlab

Can we convert matlab built in function that are present in 5G toolbox to c/c++ code using matlab coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is shown at the end of the help page of that specific function. Type

```
>> help yourFunctionName
```

at the command line. Then scroll to the very bottom and then look at *Extended Capabilities > C/C++ Code Generation*. When that is present, you should be able to generate code (please unfold to see the details).

If C/C++ Code Generation is not mentioned, you cannot generate code from that function.